# Handling the backStack with multiple fragments & activities

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, back-stack

From `SplashActivity` I am opening a `DashboardFragment`. Now from `DashboardFragment` to `ServiceListActivity` and from `ServiceListActivity` to `EditServiceActivity`.

Now when going back from `EditServiceActivity` to `ServiceListActivity` it's fine but when going back from `ServiceListActivity` to `DashboardFragment`  instead of going to `DashboardFragment`, the app is closed. Why is it happening?

Comment: Put your creash Log and Code with menifest File Here

Answer (score 0):

Put your sample code and debug log,
For reference I put sample code,
when activity transfer one to another you have to clear stack like

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Activity.this,class.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

then you should specify to every activity where to go when you press back button, so override method onBackPressed(); like

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(Activity.this, Activity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```